# 3 b+ wifi support 80 MHz ac bandwidth

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, access-point

Does the raspi 3 b+ builtin wifi support 80 MHz bandwidth under any conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raspberry Pi 3B+ does support Wifi AC at 80Mhz however a lot of people have found it to be disabled by default because of the region settings. Can you follow [this](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2619#issuecomment-410703338) and check what is the region set in your hostapd and if it is set to any country other than US, can you try changing it to US and see if that works for you

Comment: Could you please cite a reference for the fact that the 3B+ supports 80 MHz channelization?

Comment: Mine is FI, and yes, I only see narrow bands. This is more of a question of curiousity.

Comment: @Seamus: Pi3B+ uses Cypress 43455 as the wifi/bluetooth soc and the datasheet [here](http://www.cypress.com/documentation/datasheets/cyw43455-single-chip-5g-wifi-ieee-80211nac-macbaseband-radio-integrated) does mention that **WLAN operation supports rates of MCS0–MCS9 (up to 256 QAM) in 20 MHz, 40 MHz, and 80 MHz channels**. Also running `iw reg get` should report the frequency bands which other users have reported to show the 5Mhz bands at 80Mhz, ex. [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=208217)